# Scipy optimize newton secant method

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, newtons-method

Scipy optimize.newton has initial step size hard-coded as 1e-4. What's the best way to utilize this function with a different step size (ideally, specified as a parameter)?

```
# https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/optimize/zeros.py#L160

else:
    # Secant method
    p0 = x0
    if x0 >= 0:
        p1 = x0*(1 + 1e-4) + 1e-4
```

Comment: If you are sure this is a useful feature (like very very sure), you can open a feature request and ask initial step size to be added to the arguments. Better yet you can fix it yourself by substituting the `1e-4` with a variable like `initial_step` (or something) and add it to your installed version of scipy and tell scipy&#39;s people you did it and they&#39;ll merge it in the distributed version, if they see fit(not really an expert on github merge requests, sorry for the inaccuracy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial step size is not `1e-4`, it is `abs(x0)*1e-4 + 1e-4`. For example, x0 = 1000 will result in the initial step 0.1001.

If the goal is to have certain initial step size `h`, that can be achieved with a linear change of variable, `x = x0 + 1e4*h*t` where `t` is the new variable. In terms of `t`, the starting point is 0. So Newton's method will make a step of size 1e-4, which in terms of `x` translates to `h`.

Example:

```
root = newton(lambda t: func(x0 + 1e4*h*t), 0) * 1e4 * h  + x0
```

where `func` is the original function. This returns the root in terms of original variable x.